# How to cast a pointer without assignment in C?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void-pointers

I have pointers of type `void *`, but I know that they are in fact pointing to a struct. When I assign them casted to another pointer and use it, then everything works fine, but I'm not able to use the casted void pointer directly.

Here is an example:

```
typedef struct {
    int x1;
    int x2;
} TwoX;

main()
{
   void * vp;
   TwoX xx, *np, *nvp;
   xx.x1 = 1;
   xx.x2 = 2;

   vp = (void *)&xx;
   np = &xx;
   nvp = (TwoX *)vp;
   printf ("test normal pointer: %d %d\n", np->x1, np->x2);
   printf ("test recast void pointer: %d %d\n", nvp->x1, nvp->x2);
   //printf ("test void pointer: %d %d\n", (TwoX *)(vp)->x1, (TwoX *)(vp)->x2); // this line doesn't compile

}
```

The last `printf` line doesn't compile and I get the following error and warning twice (one for each casting):

```
warning: dereferencing void * pointer [enabled by default]
error: request for member x1 in something not a structure or union
```

Without that line everything works and the output is:

```
test normal pointer: 1 2
test recast void pointer: 1 2
```

How can I cast a `void *` pointer without assigning it to a new variable?

Comment: Why are you so averse to declaring a new variable?

Comment: Because it increases clutter, turning a one line instruction inside a loop to several lines, and adds declarations for variables that aren't really needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code,  change

```
printf ("test void pointer: %d %d\n", (TwoX *)(vp)->x1, (TwoX *)(vp)->x2);
```

to

```
printf ("test void pointer: %d %d\n", ((TwoX *)(vp))->x1, ((TwoX *)(vp))->x2);
                                      ^            ^      ^            ^
                                      |            |      |            |
```

Without the extra pair of parenthesis, dererence operator `->` has higher precedence over typecasting, so the `(Two *)` is not being effective before dereferencing.

As per the logic, you cannot dereference a `void` type pointer. That's why the warning. Next, when you are requesting to access some member variable of a structure pointer, the pointer is expected to be of type of that structure, which is not happenning (because it is still `void` type), so the error.

You can check the operator precedence [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).

Answer (score 4):

I think this is just an order of operations issue. Try `((TwoX*)vp)->x1`. Notice that the cast and pointer are grouped together with parentheses.